# please i need assistance with this segment of my code

Tags: c, linked-list

My code prompt the user to type in a name that the user wants to be deleted from an array of pointer then it searched through the linked list and delete the name. But my code is deleting all the name in the array of pointer with the exception of the last in the array. Here is my delete function.

```
int delete (studPtr *sPtr, Student myStud)
{

    studPtr previous = NULL;
    studPtr current = NULL;
    studPtr temp = NULL;
    while ((*sPtr)->nextPtr != NULL)
    {
        //previous = *sPtr;

        if ((*sPtr)->name == myStud.name)
        {
            temp = *sPtr;
            (*sPtr) = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
            current = (*sPtr);
            previous->nextPtr = current;
            free(temp);

        }
        else
        {
            previous = *sPtr;
            (*sPtr) = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
        }


    }
    return 1;


}
```

And here is my array of pointer

```
char *studentname[] = { "Abbie", "Oakley", "Sylvia", "Uwe", "Ken", "Aaron", "Fabien",'\0' };
```

ANd this calls the function.

```
printf("Enter students name: \n");
scanf("%s", Stud.name);
int convert_char = determineIfConvert(Stud.name);
if (convert_char == 1)
{
    convert(Stud.name);
}
int delete_student = delete(&startPtr, Stud);
if (delete_student == 1)
{
    printf("student deleted");
    printList(startPtr);
}
else
{
    printf("student not found\n");
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and use valgrind or similar. Also a debugger comes in handy.

Comment: Crystal ball says you don't know about `strcmp()`.

Comment: @EOF can you user your crystal ball to see my finals -_- .

Comment: Could you show us Student definition?

Comment: 'if ((*sPtr)->name == myStud.name)' @EOF wins a free xtal ball polishing kit.

Answer (score 1):

The last element in the array is not getting deleted because `(*sPtr)->nextPtr` is NULL at that instance and the while loop get terminated and `if ((*sPtr)->name == myStud.name)` doesnt get executed.
To solve this you can use do while loop.Before the do while loop you need to check if  (*sPtr) is `NULL` or not.